# AVFoundation capturing video with custom resolution

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, camera, avfoundation

I'm writing application on OS X, which will capture frames from camera.
Is it possible to set capture setting using `AVCaptureDevice.activeFormat` property? I had tried this, but it didn't work (session preset overrides it).

I found that on IOS it is possible with setting SessionPreset in `AVCaptureSession` to `AVCaptureSessionPresetInputPriority`.

The main purpose is to choose more detailed video resolutions than presets.

Comment: Added a bounty since I'm very interested in the answer to this question.

Specifically, I'm seeing that no matter what format I place into the AVCaptureDevice activeFormat the resolution that comes out of the preview does not change. AVCaptureSessionPresetInputPriority is not defined on mac osx, yet activeFormat is. Does this mean that activeFormat is not actually supported? I can not find documentation around this.

Answer (score 19):

**Updated: April 08, 2020**.

In macOS (unlike iOS), a capture session can automatically configure the capture format after you make changes. To prevent automatic changes to the capture format use `lockForConfiguration()` method. Then call the `beginConfiguration()` method, set properties (choose one preset out of a dozen, for instance *`AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540`*) and after that call the `commitConfiguration()` method. In the end you need to put `unlockForConfiguration()` after changing a device properties.

Or follow these steps:

- Call `lockForConfiguration()` to acquire access to the device’s config properties.
- Change the device’s `activeFormat` property (as mentioned above & below).
- Begin capture with the session’s `startRunning()` method.
- Unlock the device with the `unlockForConfiguration()`.

`startRunning()` and `stopRunning()` methods must be invoked to start and stop the flow of your data from the inputs to the outputs, respectively.

> You must also call `lockForConfiguration()` before calling the `AVCaptureSession` method `startRunning()`, or the session's preset will override the selected active format on the capture device.

**However, you might hold onto a lock, without releasing that lock, if you require the device properties to remain unchanged.**

Here are details in developer's documentation [lockForConfiguration()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1387810-lockforconfiguration).

If you attempt to set the active format to one not present in the accessible formats, will throw an `invalidArgumentException`.

[image]

Also, there's an explanation how to change properties: [macOS AVFoundation Video Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608931/mac-osx-avfoundation-video-capture)

> In AVCaptureDevice there are two properties. formats and activeFormat. format will return an NSArrary of `AVCaptureDeviceFormat` with contains all formats exposed by cam. You select any one format from this list and set it to activeFormat. Make sure that you set the format after you receive the exclusive access to the devlce by calling AVCaptureDevice `lockForConfigration`. After you set the format release the lock with AVCaptureDevice `unlockForConfigration`. Then start the AVCaptureSession which will give you the video frames of the format you set.
>
> AVCaptureFormat is a wraper for CMFormatDescription. CMVideoFotmatDescription is the concreete subclass of CMFormatDescription. Use `CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimentions()` to get the width and height in the set format. Use `CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType()` to get the video codec. For raw fotmats video codec mostly is yuvs or vuy2. For compressed formats its h264, dmb1(mjpeg) and many more.

Here's a macOS code snippet written in Swift:

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: NSViewController, 
                      AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        setupCameraSession()
        view.layer?.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        cameraSession.startRunning()
    }

    lazy var cameraSession: AVCaptureSession = {
        let session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1280x720
        return session
    }()

    lazy var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = {
        let preview =  AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.cameraSession)

        preview.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, 
                                y: 0, 
                            width: self.view.bounds.width, 
                           height: self.view.bounds.height)

        preview.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.midX, 
                                   y: self.view.bounds.midY)

        preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize
        return preview
    }()

    func setupCameraSession() {

        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
    
        do {
            let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
        
            guard let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) 
            else { return }

            // acquire exclusive access to the device’s properties
            try camera.lockForConfiguration()            
            cameraSession.beginConfiguration()
        
            camera.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
            camera.flashMode = .on
            camera.whiteBalanceMode = .continuousAutoWhiteBalance
        
            if (cameraSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) == true) {
                cameraSession.addInput(deviceInput)
            }
        
            let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString) : 
                                         NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange as UInt32)] as [String : Any]
            dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        
            if (cameraSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) == true) {
                cameraSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
            }

            let preset: AVCaptureSession.Preset = .hd4K3840x2160
            cameraSession.sessionPreset = preset
        
            cameraSession.commitConfiguration()
            camera.unlockForConfiguration()
        
            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "blah.blah.blah")
            dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a code snippet written in Objective-C setting min and max fps:

```
myCamera = NULL;
 
if ( NULL != myCamera ) {

    if ( [ myCamera lockForConfiguration: NULL ] ) {

        [ myCamera setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration: CMTimeMake( 1, 12 ) ];
 
        [ myCamera setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration: CMTimeMake( 1, 25 ) ];
 
        [ myCamera unlockForConfiguration ];
    }
}
return ( NULL != myCamera );
```

Comment: As the question describes, the active format seems to be overwritten by the session preset.

If you set activeFormat on a device, then print out the active format, you can see the change reflected.

If you then start running a session, the active format reverts back to one that maps to the session preset and the active format that was explicitly set by us is lost as soon as startRunning is called.


The question is this: How can we actually use activeFormat on mac osx? The session preset always ends up taking priority.

Comment: @DisplayName "In AVCaptureDevice there are two properties: formats and activeFormat. format will return an NSArrary of AVCaptureDeviceFormat with contains all formats exposed by cam. You select any one format from this list and set it to activeFormat. Make sure that you set the format after you receive the exclusive access to the devlce by calling AVCaptureDevice lockForConfigration. After you set the format release the lock with AVCaptureDevice unlockForConfigration. Then start the AVCaptureSession which will give you the video frames of the format you set."

Comment: Yes, I am using lockForConfiguration.

Yes i'm setting activeFormat using a format from the list returned from formats.

No, the video frames returned are not of the format I set.

Comment: OKAY, I see a way to get this to work.

It works if I explicitly do *not* call unlockForConfigration, but do call lockForConfigration.

This is counter to what the documentation says.

Comment: I'll give you the +500 (after the 24 hours) since at least you sparked an idea which helped me solve this.

Comment: OMG thank you! This has been driving me potty. It really does seem that as soon as you call unlockForConfigration() it throws away your chosen format, by design. What a braindead API...

Comment: I'm glad I could help))

Comment: I did some more experimentation... it seems the key is to call lockForConfiguration() AFTER AVSession.startRunning(). Then you can call unlockForConfiguration() after that without your chosen config/format being thrown away. This is completely counter to logical expectation, I think most device-based APIs (maybe all?) have you choose a config before starting the IO session.